# Understanding RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview

Let's assume that we have a RecyclerView with 100 rows. Every row contains a Spinner with values from 1-5 (default of 1).

I scroll down to item row #100, change it's value to 5 and then scroll back up to row #1, my questions is:

When i scroll down again to row #100, will i see the Spinner with value of 5 that i have selected earlier? or the default value of 1 since the RecyclerView will recycle items for re-use (performance boost) and not hold all 100 rows in memory.

Would love to get a good explanation on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, the `RecyclerView` will not hold the 100 rows in memory, hence the name **Recycler**View. How many views of the same layout the `RecyclerView` will hold depends on how many of them fit on the screen.

When you change item #100's value to 5, you are altering one of the recycled views. Now, until you modify that `ViewHolder` (typically done in `onBindViewHolder()`), the view will stay the same, which means that that specific `ViewHolder` will still have 5 as its `Spinner` value; at any position you are in the list, not necessarily if you scroll down to item at #100, you will see one item with the `Spinner` value of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, `RecycleView` is just that, a `View`.
So if you scroll to #100 and set spinner to 5, you need to save your selection to the underlying data array. 
That way when you scroll to #1 and back to #100, when `onBindViewHolder()` is called correct value will be loaded and spinner in #100 will show 5.
`RecycleView` only optimizes UI, as Ari mentioned.